# Double iteration through chars in a string and nodes in XSLT - how to do it with recursion?

Tags: string, xslt, char, iteration

I need to replace some characters in a string stored in `<p>` with `<app>` nodes which contain a matching char (or substring) in a child element `<lem>`. Each `<app>` contains only one `<lem>` at the top, and an arbitrary number of other nodes below it. Each `<app>` only refers to a single character in the text, and they are placed in order.

I am new to XSLT, and cannot come up with a good recursion to do this -- I'm kind of stuck in the java or MATLAB mindset of iterating over `i = 1:n` and `j= 1:m`, and I understand that this is no good for taking advantage of recursion in XSLT... Thanks for your help!!!

```
<div>
            <p>SOMEWONDERFULOLDTEXT</p>
            <app>
               <lem>O</lem>
               <rdg>Ø</rdg>
            </app>
            <app>
               <lem>W</lem>
               <rdg>V</rdg>
            </app>
            <app>
               <lem>O</lem>
               <rdg>Ö</rdg>
            </app>
            <app>
               <lem>E</lem>
               <rdg>Ë</rdg>
               <rdg>ę</rdg>
            </app>
         </div>
```

My stylesheet so far is this, but I know it doesn't work because it is iterating through the text for every `<app>`, which is wrong.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs tei" version="3.0">

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- now build the apparatus -->
    <xsl:template match="tei:div">
        <xsl:param name="thisBlock" select="./tei:p/node()"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="tei:app">
            <xsl:variable name="thisApp" select="."/>
            <xsl:for-each
                select="tokenize(replace(replace($thisBlock, '(.)', '$1\\n'), '\\n$', ''), '\\n')">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$thisApp/tei:lem/text() = .">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$thisApp"></xsl:copy-of>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates>
                </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result I want is the following, although I am getting a frightful mess with each `<app>` containing the variant readings of O printed for every single O in the text, regardless of order (of course, because I don't know how to iterate linearly along two "arrays")...

```
<div>
            <p>S<app>
               <lem>O</lem>
               <rdg>Ø</rdg>
            </app>ME<app>
               <lem>W</lem>
               <rdg>V</rdg>
            </app><app>
               <lem>O</lem>
               <rdg>Ö</rdg>
            </app>ND<app>
               <lem>E</lem>
               <rdg>Ë</rdg>
               <rdg>ę</rdg>
            </app>RFULOLDTEXT</p>
         </div>
```

Comment: I suppose there is a problem of potential ambiguities because an <app> might match several characters in the text without other disambiguating <app>s in between... In that case I think attaching it to the first encounter is good enough, but ideally I would want to throw an error message, so I can manually disambiguate them later. There should not be too many such cases anyway. The text I am working on is a historical source in Chinese, and such cases don't occur often... If I manage to somehow iterate through the text string and the series of <app>s in a linear fashion, that can be managed...

Comment: If you want to get a useful, meaningful answer, you need to provide an understandable description of the problem. I read this question twice and still don't understand what `<lem>` and `<rdg>` have to do with the text and the there are not any rules how to produce the wanted result from the provided source XML document.

Comment: I think this method of linking an apparatus to the base text is problematic when you are dealing with lemmata which are individual characters, because they will occur too often. How would you encode the case where the first `<app>` you have for a given paragraph relates to a character which is the _second_ occurrence of that character in that paragraph? You're better off using explicit pointers instead, in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, but I am kind of making eggs out of omelette right now. I have a critical edition of a Chinese text with the critical apparatus hand-typed in MS Word, and I am trying to convert that into TEI xml. In the original Word document, there are line-numbers that would have helped disambiguate, but there are no other pointers inherent to it. I suppose I could retain the line-number in the attributes of the apps...

Comment: In a critical edition of old texts, we have to take into account different manuscripts (witnesses, to be precise, because we ignore ms that are copied from another extant one), which have all accrued textual corruptions over centuries. The <lem> would be a copy of a character in the text (a chosen reading), for which there are variant readings, each of which are captured in a <rdg>. The names of the manuscripts are captured in an attribute in the <rdg>, in @wit...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose this is one way you could look at it:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="div">
    <div>
        <p>
            <xsl:call-template name="process">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="p"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="app" select="app"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </p>
    </div>  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="process">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:param name="app"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$app">
            <xsl:variable name="char" select="$app[1]/lem" />
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string, $char)" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="$app[1]"/>
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="process">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, $char)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="app" select="$app[position()>1]"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$string" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This could probably be smartened up a bit in XSLT 3.0, but I prefer the clarity of the named template method.

Answer (score 2):

The use of XSLT 3 and the request for a "recursive" approach while wanting to "iterate" makes me wonder whether `xsl:iterate` can help:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
    xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="div[p and app]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <p>
        <xsl:iterate select="app">
          <xsl:param name="text" select="p"/>
          <xsl:on-completion select="$text"/>
          <xsl:sequence select="substring-before($text, lem), 
                                .[contains($text, lem)]"/>
          <xsl:next-iteration>
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, lem)"/>
          </xsl:next-iteration>
        </xsl:iterate>
      </p>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If you remove the xpath-default-namespace="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" and xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0", it works as expected

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed, based on the original XSLT in the question I assume the input at least is in the TEI namespace, even if not shown in the input snippet. Not sure about the output but as the `app`/`lem` are not HTML I assumed it to be TEI as well.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Thanks! it worked! Yes, I have a TEI text as an input.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need recursion, if I've understood what you're trying to do. Here's how I might attack the problem:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs tei" version="3.0"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">

  <xsl:template match="p/text()">
    <!-- find the apps that applies to the current text node -->
    <xsl:variable name="apps" select="ancestor::div/app"/>
    
    <!-- parse the text node into a sequence of 1-char strings
      This weird trick uses string-to-codepoints() to tokenize 
      the string into a sequence of character codepoints, and
      then uses codepoints-to-string() to turn each integer 
      codepoint back into a 1-char string, yielding a sequence
      of characters 
    -->
    <xsl:variable name="characters" select="
      for $codepoint in 
        string-to-codepoints(.) 
      return 
        codepoints-to-string($codepoint)
    "/>

    <!-- for each character, output a matching app if
      there is one, or otherwise the character itself
    -->
    <xsl:for-each select="$characters">
      <xsl:variable name="character" select="."/>
      <xsl:variable name="app" select="$apps[lem = $character]"/>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$app">
          <xsl:copy-of select="$app"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- discard app elements -->
  <xsl:template match="app"/>

  <!-- copy everything else -->
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to:

```
<div xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
  <p>SOMEWONDERFULOLDTEXT</p>
  <app>
     <lem>O</lem>
     <rdg>Ø</rdg>
  </app>
  <app>
     <lem>W</lem>
     <rdg>V</rdg>
  </app>
  <app>
     <lem>O</lem>
     <rdg>Ö</rdg>
  </app>
  <app>
     <lem>E</lem>
     <rdg>Ë</rdg>
     <rdg>ę</rdg>
  </app>
</div>
```

Produces result:

```
<div xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
  <p>S<app>
     <lem>O</lem>
     <rdg>Ø</rdg>
  </app><app>
     <lem>O</lem>
     <rdg>Ö</rdg>
  </app>M<app>
     <lem>E</lem>
     <rdg>Ë</rdg>
     <rdg>ę</rdg>
  </app><app>
     <lem>W</lem>
     <rdg>V</rdg>
  </app><app>
     <lem>O</lem>
     <rdg>Ø</rdg>
  </app><app>
     <lem>O</lem>
     <rdg>Ö</rdg>
  </app>ND<app>
     <lem>E</lem>
     <rdg>Ë</rdg>
     <rdg>ę</rdg>
  </app>RFUL<app>
     <lem>O</lem>
     <rdg>Ø</rdg>
  </app><app>
     <lem>O</lem>
     <rdg>Ö</rdg>
  </app>LDT<app>
     <lem>E</lem>
     <rdg>Ë</rdg>
     <rdg>ę</rdg>
  </app>XT</p>
  
  
  
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am already getting something like this. The problem is I need each <app> to replace only one character, and not appear over and over again... The last part of the text "OLDTEXT" has Os and Es but they must not get replaced by the <app>s...

Comment: OK I think now I understand what you're trying to do. The order of the `<app>` elements is actually significant, and you want to iterate through the <app> elements in order, use each `<app>` to find the first character that it corresponds to, insert the `<app>` in place of that character, and then continue to process the remainder of the string using the remaining `<app>` elements. Is that correct?